# Convert message in wait_for to channel with discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have a `wait_for` method for a command to create reaction roles:

```
msg = await self.bot.wait_for('message', check=checkChannel, timeout=60)
```

It utilizes the `checkChannel` function to verify if the message is either "cancel" (to cancel the creation) or a channel in the guild. My original code:

```
def checkChannel(msg):
    if ctx.message.author == msg.author and ctx.channel == msg.channel:
        if (msg.content == "Cancel"):
            return True

        nonlocal embedChannel
        message = msg.content
        if message.startswith("<#"):
            message = message[2:len(message) - 1]

        for channel in self.bot.get_guild(ctx.guild.id).channels:
            if str(channel.id) == message:
                embedChannel = channel
                return True
        return False
    else:
        return False
```

Since this is especially messy (and doesn't account for sending the channel name), I tried looking for a more efficient method and came upon this **[answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63330723/discord-py-text-channel-check/63332985#63332985)**:

```
channel = await commands.TextChannelConverter().convert(ctx, args)
```

However, since this uses `await` and requires `async` syntax, I am unable to use it within the context of the check function and would get:

```
RuntimeWarning: coroutine '<directory>.checkChannel' was never awaited
```

How would I be able to overcome this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was told that the most efficient way to overcome it was by creating a loop (inside the outer function) and call `channel = await commands.TextChannelConverter().convert(ctx, args)` there so it could actually be called.

So in this context it would be:

```
def checkChannel(msg):
    return ctx.message.author == msg.author and ctx.channel == msg.channel

channel_checker = True

while channel_checker == True:
    try:
        msg = await self.bot.wait_for('message', check=checkChannel, timeout=60)
    except asyncio.TimeoutError:
        await ctx.send(f"You took too long to respond")
        return

    if msg == "cancel":
        await ctx.send("Cancelling...")
        return
    try:
        embedChannel = await commands.TextChannelConverter().convert(ctx, msg.content)
        channel_checker = False
    except:
        await ctx.send(f"Retry typing in the channel")

#Continue creating...
```